# Remove members from an array of char *

Tags: c, arrays, char

I've written this function to remove `count` members from `arr` at index `idx`.

```
void remove_int(int (*arr)[], int idx, int count)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        for (j = idx; (*arr)[j]; j++)
            (*arr)[j] = (*arr)[j+1];
}
```

I call it like this:

```
remove_int(&arr, index, cnt);
```

This works perfectly for *local integers*. Here's my problem. I have a header file like this:

```
struct {
    /* other stuff */
    char *array[100];
} global_struct;
```

Members in `array` are allocated and filled.

Someone figured I could just switch `int` to `char` and `int (*arr)[]` to `char *(*arr)[]`, then call:

```
remove_char(&global_struct.array, index, cnt);
```

I tried it, but it doesn't actually modify `global_struct.array`. How should I change `remove_int` to work with `global_struct.array`?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, just change `int` to `char *`. Nothing else needs to be changed.

Comment: Well then just call `free`.

Comment: Remove the `&` and stop using levels of indirection that you don't need.

Comment: @MadPhysicist If I do that `remove_int` doesn't actually modify `arr`, it modifies its own local copy of `arr`.

Comment: @Redesign there is no "local copy" in either case.  If your code isn't working and you can't figure it out after debugging, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`global_struct.array` is a pointer to `char`, and looks like it is intended to point to a string. So you need to change the function signature to something like:

```
void remove_strings(char *str[], size_t idx, size_t count);
```

I would suggest changing `idx`, `count`, `i`, and `j` to type `size_t`, as this is an `unsigned` integer type guaranteed to hold any array index. The `size_t` type has been available since C99.

Here is a demonstration program that incorporates a modified version of the `remove_int()` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct {
    char *array[100];
} global_struct;

void remove_strings(char *str[], size_t idx, size_t count);

int main(void)
{
    global_struct.array[0] = "One";
    global_struct.array[1] = "Two";
    global_struct.array[2] = "Three";
    global_struct.array[3] = "Four";
    global_struct.array[4] = "Five";
    global_struct.array[5] = NULL;

    for (size_t i = 0; global_struct.array[i]; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", global_struct.array[i]);
    }

    remove_strings(global_struct.array, 2, 2);

    putchar('\n');
    puts("After removal:");
    for (size_t i = 0; global_struct.array[i]; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", global_struct.array[i]);
    }    

    return 0;
}

void remove_strings(char *str[], size_t idx, size_t count)
{
    size_t i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        for (j = idx; str[j]; j++)
            str[j] = str[j+1];
}
```

Program output:

```
One
Two
Three
Four
Five

After removal:
One
Two
Five
```

Also, it appears that your function `remove_int()` only works on arrays of `int` that exclude `0` members, as `0` is used as a sentinel value in the inner loop of your function. It is common to terminate an array of pointers to `char` with a `NULL` pointer, as I have done, and of course a string is an array of `char`s terminated with a `'\0'`. But, it is not in general a good idea to terminate an array of `int`s with a zero. This feature of your code did make it a simple matter to adapt it to work with strings.

While your function may satisfy your current requirements, consider changing it to return the number of `int`s stored in the array. It makes sense to keep track of the number of `int`s stored in the array, and passing this value as an argument allows the function to iterate over the array without a sentinel value. Here is a revised version of your function:

```
size_t remove_ints(size_t idx, size_t count, int arr[], size_t arr_sz)
{
    size_t i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        for (j = idx; j < arr_sz; j++)
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];

    return arr_sz - count;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The purpose of "for (i = 0; i < count; i++)"?
As my understand I think you should:

```
void remove_int(int (*arr)[], int idx)
{
   int j;
     for (j = idx; (*arr)[j]; j++)
         (*arr)[j] = (*arr)[j+1];
}
```

Comment: That only removes one index.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.